# Phantom Dependencies Error

Tags: scala, cassandra, spray, phantom-dsl

I tried to integrate phantom to my project: here is my build.sbt file:

```
resolvers ++= Seq (
"Java.net Maven2 Repository"       at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/",
"Twitter Repository"               at "http://maven.twttr.com",
Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases"),
Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
Resolver.bintrayRepo("websudos", "oss-releases")
)

libraryDependencies ++= {
val phantomV = "1.27.0"
Seq(
"com.websudos"  %% "phantom-connectors"            % phantomV,
"com.websudos"  %% "phantom-dsl"                   % phantomV,
"com.websudos"  %% "phantom-example"               % phantomV,
"com.websudos"  %% "phantom-finagle"               % phantomV,
"com.websudos"  %% "phantom-thrift"                % phantomV,
"com.websudos"  %% "phantom-udt"                   % phantomV,
"com.websudos"  %% "phantom-sbt"                   % phantomV
)}
```

here is my plugin.sbt

```
def websudosPattern = {
  val pList = List("[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]")
 Patterns(pList, pList, true)}

resolvers ++= Seq(
Resolver.url("Maven ivy Websudos", 
url(Resolver.DefaultMavenRepositoryRoot))(websudosPattern))
```

I follow the link: https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki/Integrating-phantom-in-your-project

But I still got an error: unresolved dependency: com.websudos#phantom-udt_2.11;1.27.0: not found && unresolved dependency: com.websudos#phantom-sbt_2.11;1.27.0: not found

Can anyone tell me what wrong with my code. Thanks very much.

The **build.sbt**

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

  resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Java.net Maven2 Repository" at "download.java.net/maven/2/";,  
    "Twitter Repository" at "maven.twttr.com",
    Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases"),
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
    Resolver.bintrayRepo("websudos", "oss-releases")
  ) 

  libraryDependencies ++= {
    val akkaV = "2.3.9"
    val sprayV = "1.3.3"
    val phantomV = "1.27.0"
    Seq(
      "com.websudos" %% "phantom-dsl" % phantomV,
      "io.spray" %% "spray-can" % sprayV,
      "io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % sprayV,
      "io.spray" %% "spray-testkit" % sprayV % "test",
      "io.spray" %% "spray-json" % "1.3.2",
      "io.spray" %% "spray-routing-shapeless2" % sprayV,  
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaV,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaV % "test",
      "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "2.3.11" % "test"
    )
  }
```

Comment: Off topic, Spray is deprecated, you don't need an explicit dependency on Akka or Akka-teskit if you already have Spray testkit. Spray brings its own version of Akka in, and you also don't need the Specs 2 dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the documentation, all you really need to get started is:

```
val phantomV = "1.27.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.websudos"  %% "phantom-dsl" % phantomV
)
```

I have updated the documentation to correct an error on our side, the UDT module is not yet available, keep an eye out for it in future releases.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. I leave only "com.websudos"  %% "phantom-dsl" % phantomV in the build.sbt file. The error is gone. But when I tried to import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._,it shows " object websudos is not a member of package com". Is there anything I did wrong? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I did not find "com.websudos" in Referenced Libraries in my project.

Comment: @JenniferHe Can you paste your `build.sbt` somewhere here? Did you forget to `sbt reload` after adding the dependency?

Comment: Thanks very much for ur response. I did sbt reload. Here is my build.sbt file:

Comment: scalaVersion  := "2.11.6"
scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

Comment: resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Java.net Maven2 Repository"       at "http://download.java.net/maven/2/",
  "Twitter Repository"               at "http://maven.twttr.com",
  Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
  Resolver.bintrayRepo("websudos", "oss-releases")
)

Comment: libraryDependencies ++= {
  val akkaV = "2.3.9"
  val sprayV = "1.3.3"
  val phantomV = "1.27.0"
  Seq(  "com.websudos" %%  "phantom-dsl" % phantomV,
    "io.spray"   %%  "spray-can" % sprayV,
    "io.spray"   %%  "spray-routing" % sprayV,
    "io.spray"    %%  "spray-testkit" % sprayV  % "test",
    "io.spray"    %%  "spray-json"  % "1.3.2",
    "io.spray"    %%  "spray-routing-shapeless2" % sprayV,
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"   % akkaV,
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-testkit"  % akkaV % "test",
    "org.specs2" %%  "specs2-core"     % "2.3.11" % "test")}

Comment: @JenniferHe You could use `gist.github.com`, this is not easy to follow.

Comment: sorry, i have to cut the content into three parts :(

Comment: here is the link: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d5fa019279666f10695bf133c581b856. Can u see it? Thanks

Comment: @JenniferHe Thanks, this should work as expected. The only thing I can think of is the folder in which your scala files are located.

Comment: after doing "reload" "eclipse with-source=true", I got the error: 
 SERVER ERROR: Service Temporarily Unavailable url=http://maven.twttr.com/com/websudos/diesel-engine_2.11/0.3.0/diesel-engine_2.11-0.3.0-sources.jar

Comment: You should re-generate eclipse plugin files after you update your build. Try compiling from the SBT terminal, e.g go to terminal, navigate to the folder, run `sbt compile`. If that works, the problem is likely the Eclipse setup.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. The structure of my project is: MyProject/build.sbt, MyProject/project/plugins.sbt. Is it correct? I am very new to scala and spray. This is my first scala server project. I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: after running compile again. It works now. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Excellent, no worries, happy to help. Good luck with the project!

Comment: @ flavian Thanks very much! :)

Comment: @JenniferHe No worries, if you have the time please mark the answer as accepted if I've answered your question. Helps me make sure all the `phantom-dsl` questions on Stack are ticked and answered :)